# Laravel timestamps() doesn't create CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-migrations, laravel-seeding

I have a migration that has the `timestamps()` method, and then I have a seed to seed this table.

```
Schema::create('mytable', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

The seed looks like this:

```
DB::table('mytable')->insert([
    [
        'title' => 'My Awesome Title'
    ]
]);
```

When it all gets run using:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

The item gets inserted, but the values of `created_at` and `updated_at` are both `0000-00-00 00:00:00` why are they not set correctly?

here are the column schemes that it creates:

```
`created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`updated_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
```

I would like these schemes:

```
`created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`updated_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

Comment: Use Eloquent models to create records instead of the Fluent interface and they should be set correctly.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

When you insert data not using Eloquent you need to insert timestamps on your own.

If you use:

```
$x = new MyTable();
$x->title = 'My Awesome Title';
$x->save();
```

you will have timestamp filled correctly (of course you need to create `MyTable` model first)

**EDIT**

If you really want it you can change:

```
$table->timestamps();
```

into:

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
$table->timestamp('updated_at')->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
```

And if you create model for this table, you should set

```
$timestamps = false;
```

to make sure Eloquent won't try to set them on his way.

**EDIT2**

There is also one more important issue. In case you mix setting dates in tables from PHP and in other in MySQL you should make sure that both in both PHP and MySQL there's exact same datetime (and timezone) or you should use the same date comparison as you set in record (either MySQL or PHP). Otherwise when running queries you might get unexpected results for example

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE DATE(created_at) = CURDATE()
```

might be different than running query with passing PHP date

```
"SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE DATE(created_at) = '".date('Y-m-d")."'"
```

because on PHP server it might be for example 2015-12-29 but on MySQL server 2015-12-30

Comment: Okay I do have that (just commented out). So that is how it has to be done, I thought that laravel would have done that. Okay thanks

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I've added one more info in EDIT2

Answer (score 19):

For later versions, you can simply use. ([source](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/why-table-timestamps-puts-on-update-current-timestamp-on-the-created-at-column/replies/127335))

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
$table->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrent();
```

Comment: you don't need to specify $timestamps = false; with this

Comment: No, you don't because your still have the timestamps but with just different default values

Comment: A better question might be, why does Laravel timestamps() not set the on update current timestamp by default??

Answer (score 1):

i would use the carbon library if i am seeding in the timestamps and set that up in the factory. 
if not you could do something like this :

```
$timestamps = false;
```

and i would remove the  the  `$table->timestamps();` 
from the migration if i am not going to use it.