# Timestamps (updated_at, created_at) are null in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem with `updated_at`, `created_at` fields in Laravel 5.

Here is my migration:

```php
Schema::create('lots', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('lot');
    $table->integer('is_active');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

But when I insert some data into this table, `updated_at` and `created_at` fields are null. How make them auto-complete with current timestamps?

I insert data like this:

```php
\DB::table('admin_lots')->insert([
    'lot' => $request->cycle_lot,
    'is_active' => '1',
]);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us how do you insert data.

Answer (score 15):

You have to use the `create` method instead of the `insert` method in Laravel.

The `create` method automatically adds timestamps for `created_at` and `updated_at` fields:

```php
// GOOD:
User::create(array(
    'name' => 'John'
));
```

On the contrary, the `insert` method bypasses Eloquent, (it uses the query builder) and **does not update `updated_at`/`created_at`** columns!

```php
// BAD:
User::insert([
    'name' => '[[ test name ]]',
]);

dd(
    User::where(['name' => '[[ test name ]]'])->first()->create_date
);
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, i was using `insert` instead of `create` method.

Comment: In this case i am using insert() because multiple insert.. what i have to do?

Answer (score 12):

You probably do not use Eloquent when inserting data, in this case you should add timestamps manually.

If you do not want to do this, but you still need filled timestamps, [use this hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515938/laravel-timestamps-doesnt-create-current-timestamp):

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
$table->timestamp('updated_at')->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
```

**Update**

Based on your updated code, here's another solution:

```
\DB::table('admin_lots')->insert([
                'lot'   => $request->cycle_lot,
                'is_active'     => '1',
                'created_at' = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),
                'updated_at' = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()
            ]);
```

Comment: Updated post on how I insert data. Thanks for your answer, will try it now.

Comment: Added another solution for manual timestamp creation based on your code.

Comment: It seems like the a use case for eloquent to be honest. The straight db insert is a bad practice in this case.

Comment: Thanks! Both solutions work for me, but 1st one is better. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @overburn, I've posted first solution when OP didn't provide any code and I wrote it's a kind of **hack**.

Comment: True. But that hack is bound to give somebody else headaches down the road.

Answer (score 8):

Check if your model has this line.

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

If it has, delete it.

Comment: If the line is in a parent class, you have to add: public $timestamps = true;

Answer (score 5):

When you instert data directly, Laravel won't know about your timestamps. 
You can either set the timestamps manually in the insert statement, or switch to using Eloquent models , which handle many things out of the box for you, including timestamps. It's also way easier to maintain than straight queries, where applicable.

[Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent)

Comment: I really recommend using Eloquent in this case. Anything else will result in unnecessary difficult maintainable non-laravel way code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Laravel's awesome Eloquent feature to make timestamps written to the Database automatically...

As by seeing your example the code for eloquent will go something like this:

```
$lot_inputs = array(
    'lot' => $request->cycle_lot,
    'is_active' => 1
);
$new_lot = Lot::create($lot_inputs);
```

Please note that you should have the Model for the table = 'lots' (and it must extend Eloquent) so that you can easily use Eloquent methods and its properties...

It would be great if you use [Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent) as much as possible so that if in future you want to change your DB technology then you won't need to specify the written eloquent queries again (e.g: the conversion of query to different DB languages is automatically done by Eloquent)

Thanks I hope this will help you to resolve your issue..!!

Answer (score 0):

The columns shouldn't auto-initialize at the database level. That is handled by Eloquent

---

Do not use

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
$table->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrentOnUpdate();
```

**TLDR;**

- You can't call CURRENT_TIMESTAMP twice in a table
- You are required to declare a default value or change the column to be nullable

See:

- https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/12060
- https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/874
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html