# php artisan default created_at column is NULL instead of current datetime

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I create migration like this: `php artisan make:migration create_categories_table --create categories`

Then I add some columns, like:

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 150);
        $table->timestamps();
});
```

and then: `php artisan migrate`

This creates table `categories`, then I insert into categories:

```
 insert into categories
 (name)
 values
 ('sport')
```

This inserts row but `created_at` column is `null` instead of current timestamp.

What is my mistake?

I did (mysql command): `show create table categories`:

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` ( `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`name` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL, 
`updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) 
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4     
COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

which clearly shows that default value for `created_at` is NULL. Why?

Comment: How do you do the insert?

Comment: Using raw sql editor

Comment: timestamps are filled when you insert with Laravel/eloquent. Timestamps do not have a default value upon creation. Check how to set defaults [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067614/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-of-a-timestamp-column-to-the-current-timestamp-w)

Comment: you should rollback that migration then run `php artisan migrate --pretend` to see the SQL it generates .. the timestamp fields need to be updated when you insert/update the record

Comment: I edited question with `show create table categories`. tis shows that table is created with `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL`. What is reason of this?

Comment: probably because of all the fun issues between different databases and these 2 particular timestamp fields when it comes to on create and on update

Comment: The `created_at` and `updated_at` fields are updated through Eloquent (when using `$table->timestamps()` they are default `NULL`), so you should use an Eloquent Model to insert/update the data if you want to touch those fields. Otherwise you have to specify the columns yourself with the default `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067614/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-of-a-timestamp-column-to-the-current-timestamp-w) it might be help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using,

```
$table->timestamps();
```

use,

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
$table->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrent();
```

It will set default value of created at column and updated at column. then after it will store current timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need those columns to have a default value, it's by design.

The `created_at` and `updated_at` values are **automatically managed by Laravel's Eloquent**.

Just make sure you don't write manual insert queries, or [even use the `insert` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36998228/timestamps-updated-at-created-at-are-null-in-laravel-5)

https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#timestamps